# Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric even after convert them to numerical variables

Tags: r, pca

I have just started to learn R few days ago. I'm trying to run PCA using R (ver. 4.0.3) under R console based on the tutorial here (https://www.benjaminbell.co.uk/2018/02/principal-components-analysis-pca-in-r.html#further)

My data consists of 2 categorical variables (`SPECIES` & `STATE`) and 4 numeric variables, and the categorical variables are important to my PCA and cannot be removed.

I loaded my excel data (**dataset1.csv**) as **dataset2** and I tried converting them to numerical variables using:

```
#1
d = data.frame(Species=c("EA", "EH", "ES"), x=runif(3), y=runif(3))

#2
d$Species = as.numeric(as.factor(d$Species))

#3
3. d = data.frame(State=c("Kelantan", "Terengganu", "Pahang", "Johor"), x=runif(4), y=runif(4))

#4
d$State = as.numeric(as.factor(d$State))
```

See tutorial: [Principal Components Analysis:Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172274/principal-components-analysiserror-in-colmeansx-na-rm-true-x-must-be-n)

However, when I use the code: `p <- prcomp(dataset2)`, I'm still getting the error:

> Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Any helps in enabling me to run PCA using both categorical and numeric variables are much appreciated.

P/S: I have previously worked with FactorMineR and Factoshiny but I don't see the option to help me labelled states as different icons and species by different colors, etc.

Comment: You need to post a fully reproducible example. I didn't get an error when running lines 1 and 2 followed by `prcomp()`. Run `dput(head(dataset2))` to provide a sample of your data set.

Comment: Subsetting out the factor columns of dataset2 and then running `prcomp()`. For example, if the factor column is column 1 in dataset2, try running: `prcomp(dataset2[, -c(1)]`. If you have more than one column that is not numeric, subset those as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is your problem!  I just converted what you did but it works. Please just copy and paste the code then run. It will work.

```
 d = data.frame(State=c("Kelantan", "Terengganu", "Pahang", "Johor"), x=runif(4), y=runif(4))
> str(d)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ State: Factor w/ 4 levels "Johor","Kelantan",..: 2 4 3 1
 $ x    : num  0.4941 0.0722 0.206 0.4999
 $ y    : num  0.266 0.177 0.133 0.442
> d$State = as.numeric(as.factor(d$State))
> d
  State          x         y
1     2 0.49413147 0.2664495
2     4 0.07220937 0.1772339
3     3 0.20597378 0.1326426
4     1 0.49994185 0.4415824 
> prcomp(d)
Standard deviations (1, .., p=3):
[1] 1.31234286 0.07598757 0.05476076

Rotation (n x k) = (3 x 3):
             PC1         PC2       PC3
State  0.9837020 -0.04918652 0.1729481
x     -0.1549119 -0.72014961 0.6763038
y     -0.0912835  0.69207314 0.7160322
```